# OCaml - implement a histogram function

Tags: recursion, ocaml, histogram

I have a project I am working on and I need to implement a histogram function in OCaml. I have to write a function that takes a list as an argument and returns a histogram, in the form of a list of tuples. It would look something like this:

```
histogram [1;2;3;1;1;3];;
[(1,3);(2,1);(3,2)]
```

I can't however get this to work. I feel like I am pretty close but I just need some help / guidance on how to finish the actual histogram function. So far I have made it check a list (nl) for anything that may already be in there. If it doesnt contain the number already I add it to the list. My problem is that I dont know how to recall the function once I have added it to the list. See my code for where the problem lies.

```
let check a ls = match (a,ls) with
|a,[] -> false
|a,xs -> if fst (hd xs) != a then check a (tl xs) else true


let rec count a ls = match ls with
|[] -> 0
|x::xs -> if x = a then 1 + count a xs else 0 + count a xs

let nl = []    

let rec histo l = match l with
|[]-> []
|x::xs -> if check x nl then histo xs else nl @ [(x,count x l)] *******
```

I need to re call histo where the ****** are. Any help at all will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty clearly a school assignment, so I'll just give a few hints.

- You seem to expect to modify `nl` in your `histo` function. But OCaml variables are immutable. The variable named `nl` in your code will always be bound to an empty list. This is usually the first thing to figure out in FP: how to work with immutable values.
- As a hint, the essence is to pass values like `nl` as *parameters* of your function. A function's parameters can (of course) be different in different calls to the function.
- I don't follow your code for when `x` appears in `nl` (`check` returns true). In this case you need to create a list with an incremented count. But your code just continues without doing anything in particular.
- If you redefine `histo` to take all the required parameters, your unfinished case just needs to call `histo` with the right parameters.

Answer (score 0):

toastedDeli, just a little advice about your function count. You can use more pattern matching:

```
let rec count a ls = match ls with
  |[]              -> 0
  |x::xs  when x=a -> 1 + count a xs
  |_::xs           -> count a xs

let rec count a = function
  |[]              -> 0
  |x::xs  when x=a -> 1 + count a xs
  |_::xs           -> count a xs
```